# How to localize the format of the return address in MS Word when printing an envelope?

Tags: macos, ms-word

When printing an envelope in Microsoft Word for Mac 2018 you can chose to "Use my address". Without allowing Word access to Apple Contacts, this information is retrieved from the "User Information" provided in the settings of Word. Independent of your regional settings or the display language of Word, the result will look something like this:

```
John Doe
123 Main Street
Anytown, California 12345
```

However, outside the U.S. the standard format of a mailing address may look different. In many European countries for example, the postal code appears to the left of the city name.

Therefore, I wonder how can the address layout in Microsoft Word be customized, in particular for the sender address on the envelope?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved the problem using Apple Contacts and AutoText in Word:

1. Set up your My Card in Apple Contacts and provide your mailing address as **work** (important!) address.
2. Grant Word access to Apple Contacts in System Preferences: "Security & Privacy", then click "Privacy". Select "Contacts" on the left and check "Microsoft Word" on the right.
3. Back in Word, compose your favorite address layout using name fields from the Personal Address Book (PAB) or Outlook Contacts (OAB). For example:

   ```
   {{<PR_GIVEN_NAME> <PR_SURNAME> | <PR_DISPLAY_NAME>}}{<PR_COMPANY_NAME>}
   {{<PR_STREET_ADDRESS>}
   {{<PR_POSTAL_CODE>} {<PR_LOCALITY>}} 
   {<PR_COUNTRY>}}
   ```
4. Finally, create a new AutoText entry in Word ("Insert", then "AutoText") from this snippet. Note that the name of this AutoText entry **must** correspond to the translation of "AddressLayout" in the display language of your Word. Here a few examples for some specific languages:

   - English: AddressLayout
   - Danish: AdresseLayout
   - Dutch: AdresIndeling
   - French: MiseEnPageAdresse
   - German: Adresslayout
   - Italian: IndirizzoLayout

That's it. After spending far too long to work this out, I hope these hints help some of you save a bit of time.

Comment: See Change Envelope Layout by Graham Mayor. http://www.gmayor.com/changing_envelope_layout.htm --- note this is not really an appropriate question for Stack Overflow. It would be appropriate on Super User. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word  Stack Overflow is about programming. It would not surprise me if this question is moved or deleted.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue! The link you provide is about changing the font style and the position of the address – it does not answer the question posted here.

Comment: Sorry about that. Take a look at the related article on changing the Return Address: http://www.gmayor.com/Alternative_Return_Addresses.htm --- You are unlikely to get a substantive answer here, though.I believe that people can lose reputation points by posting an answer to an off-topic question.

Comment: Thanks again for your effort, but the article you refer to explains how to set up alternative return addresses, it does not answer the question of this post which is how to customize the structure of the return address.